# date-fns: how to define a default locale app-wide?

Tags: javascript, date-fns

It's pretty straightforward to set a locale in a per-function call basis:

```
import { formatRelative, subDays } from 'date-fns'
import { ptBR } from 'date-fns/locale'

formatRelative(subDays(new Date(), 3), new Date(), { locale: ptBR })
```

But how do I set a default locale to be used app-wide?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I know, there is no such option. Usually I create custom wrapper function around `formatDate` functions and pass there application locale. You could store locale in global variables or in app level stores:

**formatRelativeWrap.js**

```
import { formatRelative } from 'date-fns'
import AppStore from 'appStore'

export default (date1, date2, locale) => {
    return formatRelative(date1, date2, { locale: locale || AppStore.defaultLocale})
}
```

As [@Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182668/pointy) mentioned there is note about this in official docs - https://date-fns.org/v2.22.1/docs/I18n - second example.

Comment: This is in the date-fns documentation, complete with example code.

Comment: (I meant that comment supportively, if that's not clear.)

Answer (score 14):

This has been released in version 2.29: https://date-fns.org/v2.29.0/docs/setDefaultOptions

```
// Set global locale:
var setDefaultOptions = require('date-fns/setDefaultOptions')
import { es } from 'date-fns/locale'
setDefaultOptions({ locale: es })
```